# Bottom up chart parser adding active arc step

Tags: parsers, natural-language-processing

I am following Bottom up chart parsing algorithm from  Natural Language Understanding book by James Allen. It is

[image]

I couldn't understand the 3rd step. I thought that when active arc is added the dot is advanced. But dot is indroduced in the third step. The example says that

[image]

This example shows dot is advanced. But step 3 says otherwise

Comment: It looks like few users have access to that book. Can you provide a link that shows several page or even a whole chapter?

Comment: @Apass.Jack 1995

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have spotted a typo in that book.

The dot $\circ$ in step 3 of figure 3.11 should be after constituency C. To be explicit and precise, step 3 should be stated as the following.

> 3. For each rule in the grammar of form X $\to$ C X$_1$ ... X$_n$, add an active arc of form X $\to$ C $\circ$ X $_1$ ... X$_n$ from position P$_1$ to P$_2$.

As you have observed, all examples following figure 3.11 show clearly that the dot $\circ$ are placed after constituency C.

This can also be verified by the statement a few lines below.

> Notice that active arcs are never removed from the chart.

We can check that we cannot, indeed, find any instance of an active arc in all of section 3, chapter 3 of the book that starts with a $\circ$.

There is also a rule that for each active arc from position $a$ to $b$, the symbols before the $\circ$ should correspond to the terminals between those positions inclusively. That rule also implies that a dot $\circ$ cannot be at the very front of an active arc.

By the way, that books is written so clearly that I have to say that glaring typo is an almost reverse testimonial.